# VBA - IBAN validation not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, power-query, screen-scraping

I have a list of IBANs in Excel and wish to validate them via scraping data through VBA from this website: https://www.iban.com/iban-checker. In column A (cells A2:A3000), I have the IBANs and in column B I wish to see whether they are valid or not based on the IBAN Checker website.

It may be also worthwhile to extract/validate the BIC code in another column. Thus, would be glad to hear your opinion on this as well.

I have the following VBA code for the IBAN  validation for now, which is not working, unfortunately:

Sub Iban()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim htmldoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlim As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlims As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim URL As String
Dim sBody As String

Dim Iban As String

Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

uf = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

'   Sh.Range ("f2:F" & uf).ClearContents

```
URL = "https://es.iban.com/iban-checker"

For x = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Iban = Sh.Cells(x, 1).Value
    
    sBody = "iban=" & Iban
    
    XMLPage.Open "Post", URL, False
    XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    XMLPage.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
    
    XMLPage.send sBody
    
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    
    Set htmlims = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("strong")
    For Each htmlim In htmlims
        If htmlim.innerText = "VÁLIDO" Then
                Sh.Cells(x, 2).Value = 100
        End If
        If htmlim.innerText = "Invalid IBAN check digit!" Then
                Sh.Cells(x, 2).Value = 52323432
        End If
    Next htmlim
```

Next htmlim
Next

End Sub

Can you please help me with this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "not working"?  Wrong result? Error message? Excel crash? computer crash?  Please be specific.

Comment: looks like you have 2 `Next htmlim`. also in your `For` does `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` give you a number?

Comment: and last `Next` should be `Next x`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even I am having same issue. I have used the above code but not able to validate the IBANs in excel sheet. How do I do it? I am new to VBA

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).